# How do I access structured metadata using DocPad?

Tags: metadata, docpad

I'm evaluating DocPad at the moment to see if it will be suitable for our website amongst other things. I'm having trouble working out how to use structured metadata in eco templates. I'm pretty sure it's related to [How to display Backbone nested attribute using Eco?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521705/how-to-display-backbone-nested-attribute-using-eco) but that's unanswered too.

My page looks like:

```
--- yaml
layout: 'post'
title: "Samuel Johnson's garret - an unexpected lull"
category: 'Digital Publishing'
author: 
    name: Author Name
    page: author
    email: author.name@ourdomain.co.uk
---


Unexpected free time, a chilly walk, a brown plaque leads me to 
[Dr Johnson's house (http://www.drjohnsonshouse.org/) near Fleet-Street…
```

and the eco template like:

```
---
layout: default
---

<article id="post" class="post">
    <h1><%= @document.title %></h1>
    <h2>By: <%= @document.author.email %></h2>
    <div class="post-content"><%- @content %></div>
</article>
```

The `@document.author.email` leads to the following error being logged:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

How do I access that structured metadata?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Everything seems ok. When I test the same structure, the line `<%= @document.author.email %>` works. Maybe you have some kind of inconsistency using white spaces and tabs ? You can validate your YAML on this site : http://yamllint.com.

Personally I also use arrays of objects in metadata :

```
choices:
  - 
    text: "Mercure"
    feedback: "Mercure est la planète la plus proche du Soleil, elle se situe à une distance de 0,4 UA"
    value: 0

  - 
    text: "Neptune"
    feedback: "C'est effectivement la planète la plus éloignée avec une distance de 30 UA."
    value: 1
```

and it works great. Sorry for the text in French but I guess it doesn't really matter for an example.

Comment: Dammit. Should have thought of that! Whitespace error on the first line of the nested associative array. Thank you for making me think.

Comment: Hmmm. Even with valid YAML, that doesn't resolve the basic problem.

Comment: Is your docpad up-to-date ? Back to october, there was some issue with the YAML parser.

Comment: Yes, updated last Sunday. I'm doing something wrong but failing to see what it is.

Comment: have you tried to use this syntax `author: {name: "john doe", email: "john.doe@example.com"}` ?

Comment: Also try `<h2>By: <%= @document.author?.email or 'unknown' %></h2>` perhaps there is a template where author isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this example, it works perfectly now, i found my issue and i want to share the solution with you:

```
---
  slides: 
    -
      detailimage: "heliski-img.png"
      mainimage: "heliski-g.jpg"
      title: "Powder South Heliski Guides"
    -
      detailimage: "nuevos-vientos-img.png"
      mainimage: "nuevos-vientos.jpg"
      title: "Centro Experiencial Nuevos Vientos"
---

#full-width-slider.royalSlider.heroSlider.rsMinW
  each slide in document.slides
    .rsContent
      img.rsImg(src='/slideshow/#{slide.mainimage}', alt='#{slide.title}')
      .infoBlock.infoBlockLeftBlack.rsABlock(data-fade-effect='', data-move-offset='10', data-move-effect='bottom', data-speed='200')
      p #{slide.title}
        img.rsImg(src='/slideshow/#{slide.detailimage}', alt='#{slide.title}')
```

the important thing is the each line, it must say "in document.slides" so i can access from jade the document metadata. :D

the final render will look like this:

```
<div id="full-width-slider" class="royalSlider heroSlider rsMinW">
  <div class="rsContent"><img src="/slideshow/heliski-g.jpg" alt="Powder South Heliski Guides" class="rsImg">
    <div data-fade-effect="" data-move-offset="10" data-move-effect="bottom" data-speed="200" class="infoBlock infoBlockLeftBlack rsABlock"></div>
    <p>Powder South Heliski Guides</p><img src="/slideshow/heliski-img.png" alt="Powder South Heliski Guides" class="rsImg">
  </div>
  <div class="rsContent"><img src="/slideshow/nuevos-vientos.jpg" alt="Centro Experiencial Nuevos Vientos" class="rsImg">
    <div data-fade-effect="" data-move-offset="10" data-move-effect="bottom" data-speed="200" class="infoBlock infoBlockLeftBlack rsABlock"></div>
    <p>Centro Experiencial Nuevos Vientos</p><img src="/slideshow/nuevos-vientos-img.png" alt="Centro Experiencial Nuevos Vientos" class="rsImg">
  </div>
</div>
```